# zip cycle a list is printing characters instead of string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a sentence out of dataframes rows.

I have a dataframe with columns

```
df = df[['fullName', 'Location', 'College', 'Degree_location', 'Degree', 'Jobs', 'Company',  'Date', 'LocationJob', 'Avg_rounded']]
```

I'm trying to match each row of the column with a hardcoded sentence ie

```
name_placeholder = "My name is "
location_placeholder = "I live in "
college_placeholder = "I went to "
collloc_placeholder = " in "
degree_placeholder = "I have a degree in "
job_placeholder = "I have work as "
company_placeholder = " in companies "
date_placeholder = "I have work from "
jobloc_placeholder = "My job locations have been "
avgdistance_placeholder = "The average distance between my locations is "
placeholders = name_placeholder, location_placeholder, college_placeholder, collloc_placeholder, degree_placeholder, job_placeholder, company_placeholder, date_placeholder, jobloc_placeholder, avgdistance_placeholder
```

Where I expect it to end like "My name is [fullName]. I live in [Location]. I went to [College] " and so forth

If I use a for loop to access the rows of the dataframe ie:

```
for x in profiles:
  for y in x:
     print(y)
```

I got the expected results.

However, I'm trying to make sentences out of the dataframe.

I have tried

```
for x in profiles:
  for y in x:
    for pl, pr in zip(cycle(placeholders), y):
       print(pl + pr)
```

But this gives me

```
My name is A
I live in d
I went to a
 in m
I have a degree in
```

Why is the dataframe row printing each character instead of the full string ie [fullName]?

From my understanding, I'm combining the dataframe and placeholders list and I'm cycling through placeholders since it's a much shorter list than the dataframe.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `profiles` is a row in `df`, you don't need `for y in x` as that is attempting to iterate every character in each string value in the row. Just use:

```py
for x in profiles:
    for pl, pr in zip(cycle(placeholders), x):
         print(pl + pr)
```